# Cast WPF property in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm wondering if it's possible to cast properties in WPF ?

I've this code

```xml
<Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Window.Loaded">
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Window.Opacity)" From="0.0" To="0.92" Duration="0:0:0.15" AutoReverse="False" />
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
</Window.Triggers>
```

and i want to modify my window background opacity but i need to cast Window.Background to SolidColorBrush that's why i'm wondering if it's possible and if yes how to do it (and if not if you have a good way to do it)

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Please try **ColorAnimation** functionality. Usually, #00000000 stands for transparent a hex colour with additional two zeros for the opacity at the start, in the format of **aRGB**. Set the colour of the window to the colour mentioned above. and in the colour animation set it to the desired colour.

try this

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Window.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <ColorAnimation To="#FF000000" 
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Window.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" 
                                    FillBehavior="Stop" 
                                    Duration="0:0:0.15"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
```

Hope this helps.